# SP2010: Need to filter list items returned by caml query

Tags: caml

I'm using SPServices and unslider.js to display a slideshow on a page. Instead of showing all items in the slider, the requirement is to manage the slides by using a filtered view. 
I added  tags but I don't know caml and how to specify the view required.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var sliderList = "Slider"; // Name of the list that contains slides
      var slideContentField = "HTML"; //Name of the Rich text field that has slide content
      var slideBackgroundImageField = "Picture"; //Name of the picture field to use as background image
      HillbillySlider(sliderList,slideContentField,slideBackgroundImageField);
  });
 function HillbillySlider(sliderList,slideContentField,slideBackgroundImageField) {
     //query to retrieve all items
     var query = "<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'></Value></Neq></Where></Query></View>";
     //return fields for slide content and background picture
     var camlViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='"+slideContentField+"' /><FieldRef Name='"+slideBackgroundImageField+"' /></ViewFields>";
     $().SPServices({
          operation: "GetListItems",
          async: true,
          listName: sliderList,
          CAMLViewFields: camlViewFields,
          CAMLQuery: query,
          completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
               $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
               var slideContent = ($(this).attr("ows_"+slideContentField));
               var picture = $(this).attr("ows_"+slideBackgroundImageField)==undefined?"":$(this).attr("ows_"+slideBackgroundImageField).split(",")[0];
               //create slide (li) and append it to other slides
               $("#hillbillySlider").append("<li style=\"background-image: url('"+picture +"');\">"+slideContent+"</li>");
          }); // end completefunc
          //start the slider
          $('.hillbillyBanner').unslider();
        }
     }); // end SPServices call
 }
```

Comment: so this returns no items?

Comment: It returns ALL the items - that's the problem. In my answer I clarify how I was able to filter the items.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, but you need to query on an ID if that's the parm you have. Also, remove the `<View>` tag from your query:

```
<Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>" + id + "</Value></Neq></Where></Query>
```

This will return all Items except the one with that ID. I'm not sure that you even need the CAMLViewFields argument unless you only want those two fields returned

Comment: Thanks - I was doing it all wrong and got it figured out.

Comment: Np. +1 if I helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching it the wrong way. Through force of habit, I was trying to get the list view involved to do the filtering, but I realized I can "roll my own view" and filter directly in the query with:

```
<Query><Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'></Value></Neq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active0' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>
```

So only items that have a "yes" value in a yes/no field show up.